# Is there any connection between all the psychopaths called Morgan?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer, angel

One of my favourite characters in [Angel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_(1999_TV_series)) is Lilah Morgan - a character who basically revels in her own evil, not for any great purpose, but because she likes her comforts, enjoys her work, and doesn't particularly care about treading on anyone in order to get what she wants.  She is basically a classic [psychopath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychopathy).  However, I've noticed recently a couple of other characters who seem to share both her surname and her affliction.

In [Dexter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dexter_%28TV_series%29), the title character Dexter Morgan is a psychopathic serial killer, who is unable to control his urges.

In [Luther](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luther_%28TV_series%29), Dr Alice Morgan is also a psychopathic serial killer, albeit much closer in
personality to Lilah than to Dexter.

Is there any reason for the proliferation of psychopathic murderers called Morgan?  Are any of these deliberate references to the other?  Is there a common source?  Are there any more examples?

Comment: Morgan le Fay, perhaps?

Comment: Could just be coincidence? [Morgan](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rMGtxDxGjM) is a pretty common name.

Comment: Yes, it could completely be a co-incidence.  If so it's a surprising one.  Hence the question.

Comment: Speaking of psychopathic killers, how about Samara Morgan, the girl in the well from The Ring. <shudder>

Comment: Well, while not precisely a pychopath, but definitely exhibiting similar tendancies, there is Warden Donald Morgan from the Dresden novels.

Comment: Could be going out on a limb here, but 'Morgan' can imply 'Morgenstern', the German for "Morning Star", which is strongly associated with Lucifer.

Comment: Maybe a wink to Henry Morgan the pirate?

Comment: Or, no more meaningful that the number of crimnals with the middle name "Wayne" (as noted in the "News of the Wierd" mailing list.

Comment: Circa 1980, Marvel and DC both had newspaper comics, and at one point each had an antagonist named Loomis.  I think at least one of them was a mad scientist, but that may be mental contamination from Loomis Lab at UIUC.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The name almost certainly draws inspiration from [Morgan le Fay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morgan_le_Fay), the antagonist of many King Arthur stories. Certainly it is fair to consider her an prototypical villain. The linked Wikipedia article does give some etymological insight into the name... and as the comments here suggest, there are many more examples of villains with that name or variations thereof.

Don't name your kid Morgan.

[edit] Credit to Micah, didn't see his Sept 5 comment when I first answered.